# Angular Guard redirect to root

Tags: angular

I created a guard, to take care of my authentication, and I used `canActivate` to activate this guard. However, when I go to the route that will be authenticated, in a brief moment I am redirected the root URL and then it goes to the expected url.
I do not want the user to not see an expected page, so my question is, is there a way to prevent it from going to that root url?

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  this.router.navigate(['/painel/login']);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: can you share your routing.ts file as well

Comment: There's definitely some issue with your route config. Please share that as well in the question and someone will be able to have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  this.router.navigate(['/painel/login']);
  return true;
}
```

Your guard implementation is incorrect. It must

- return true, or a promise of true, or an observable emitting true if the user is allowed to navigated to the guarded route
- return false, or a promise of false, or an observable emitting false if the user is not allowed to navigate to the guarded route.

In the second case, since you also want to display the login page (and not just prevent the guarded route to be activated), then you can navigate to the login route.

But your guard always tells the router that the user is allowed to go to the guarded route (so, the router allows the navigation), and it also tells it to navigate to the login page (so, then, it goes to the login page).

So your guard should look like

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  if (!this.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/painel/login']);
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```